# how to use more than one generic in a function in C#

Tags: c#

I want to use more than one generic for a function but this doesn't work

```
  protected async Task<Tlist,T> Send<Tlist,T>(string url,HttpMethod method,DateTimeSyncedAt ) where Tlist,T:class
    {
    }
```

[image: I get these error]

Comment: `Task<T>` only has one generic parameter. What are you hoping to do?

Comment: This works: `protected async Task<R> Send<T, R>(T source) where T : class where R : class`. Does that help?

Comment: yes it works thanks

Comment: @regestea23 - What "works"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Task won't support giving back multiple types as return value.

So you can use it as basically like

```
Task<T>
//The following wont work
Task<T,T1>
```

But you can do with using tuples or anything that is `value pair`

** Value Pairs **

Tuples:

> A tuple is a data structure that has a specific number and sequence of values. The Tuple<T1,T2> class represents a 2-tuple, or pair, which is a tuple
> Tuples are usually used by their operator
> (T, T1)
> Types in tuples could be more than two this depends on the use case.

Dictionaries:

> Dictionary in C# is the generic collection type in the System.Collection.Generics namespace that contains Keys and Values.

Dictornary could be initialized by:

```
    new Dictionary<string, string>(new []{new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SOMETHING1","SOMETHING2")});
```

If you wrap this dictionary to a variable our case called `dictionary` you can access the keys and the values separately by the following

```
dictionary.Keys // this is an array of keys in the dictionary
dictionary.Values // this is an array of values in the dictionary
```

Do this as the following:

```
    protected async Task<(TList, T)> Send<TList,T>(string aParam,string bParam, string cParam) where TList : IEnumerable<T> where T : struct
    {
    }
```

This will return a tuple with the specified types in this case `(item1: LIST_OF_GUID, GUID)`

But you can use this with any type of constrains

Comment: What does "anything that is valuable to value pair" mean?

Comment: What does "anything that is value to value pair" mean?

Comment: Sorry It meant to be `value to value` pair it's like tuples or even Dictionaries. These are types where you have a value paired with value. Will describe in my answer in a sec.

Comment: I've tried to explain it to you as much as I could. I hope I've been able to help you.

Comment: The phrase "value to value pair" is a bit odd. I'd either say a "value pair" or a "value to value mapping" - depending on what you actually mean by it.